# Proxmox and PXE boot

Tags: cluster, raid5, pxe-boot, proxmox, dell-powervault

I have 10 rack servers, each has an 80 GB hard drive, and a Dell PowerVault with no hard drives.

It is possible to take all these hard drives and put them in the PowerVault cluster, then boot proxmox on pxe with my rack servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running proxmox from PXE boot is not supported. Installation from PXE boot is possible, however you still need the local drives in the machine.

Comment: +1 Usually regardless of OS you need some sort of local logical disk present for paging and other system processes that don't run in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually lets make the post more clear. It is possible to run Proxmox from PXE BUT it's not documented or supported. I recommend only advanced users try. If you get it working its amazing. You can run all your vm's straight from RAM and do not need hard drives in the system at all.